# How can i change from backgroud=False to background=True in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongoengine

I am trying to set `background=True` in the meta of `Mongoengine`.

```
meta = {
    'indexes': [
        {'fields': ['-serviceName', '-user'],
         'sparse': True,
         'types': False,
         'background': True},
    ]
}

collection.create_index(fields, background=background, **opts)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: create_index() got multiple values for keyword argument 'background'
```

and by default the background is set to `False`

Answer (score 1):

The keyword to use is `index_background`, not `background`:

```
meta = {
    'indexes': [
        {'fields': ['-serviceName', '-user'],
         'sparse': True,
         'types': False,
         'index_background': True},
    ]
}
```

see [the docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html?highlight=background#global-index-default-options) and [the code](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/7748e68440df2e3ad2d48ec0b55b9647c4de014d/mongoengine/document.py#L752).